# electron-packager - Generated exe stays in memory after closing the window

Tags: electron

So I am using the electron-packager cli tool and everything is working EXCEPT the generated exe (only tried on Windows so far) doesn't unload from memory when I close the window (my one and only renderer process). I have to close it (kill the process) using task manager.

Is there something inside of electron I can call to ensure that this happens or is this a bug in electron-packager or what?

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this I considered that unloading the window doesn't automatically unload the node process and added the following 'closed' event to my mainWindow:

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    });
    // This 'closed' handler solves the problem
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null;
        process.exit(0);
    });
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    mainWindow.setMenu(menu);
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
});
```